# Checkbox in one table controls checkboxes in another

Tags: jquery

I have the following function where a top checkbox controls other checkboxes in the table.

```
var $checkboxes = $("#myTbl input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)").
        not($("#myTbl input[disabled=disabled]")).
        change(function() {
            var allIsChecked = $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
            $all[0].checked = allIsChecked;     
            enableProcessTagBtn();          
        });

var $all = $("#allCheckboxes").change(function() {
    $checkboxes.attr("checked", this.checked);
    enableBtn();
});

function enableBtn() {
    if ($("#myTbl input[type=checkbox]").filter(":checked").length > 0) {
        $("#Btn").removeClass("disabledBtn").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#Btn").addClass("disabledBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
enableBtn();

<table id="myTbl">
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="allCheckboxes"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input name="" type="button" id="Btn">
```

I need help re-writing the function where the `#allCheckboxes` check-box is in one table and the rest are in another table:

```
<table id="myTbl1">
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="allCheckboxes"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="myTbl2">
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input name="" type="button" id="Btn">
```

Please note that unless ALL checkboxes are selected, the top one won't be selected. Ex. If all are selected and then one of them is unchecked, the top one would get unchecked too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RLApb/1/) for working solution

You can give the other checkboxes a class and check them based on the value of the controlling checkbox:

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){

    $('#allCheckboxes').click(function(){
        $('.otherChecks').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });

    var numChecks = $('.otherChecks').length;

    $('.otherChecks').click(function(){
        var allChecked = $('.otherChecks:checked').length === numChecks;

        $('#allCheckboxes').prop("checked", allChecked);

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="myTbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>All <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="allCheckboxes"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="myTbl2">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="otherChecks"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="otherChecks"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It doe select but it breaks other functionality. For example, currently if all checkboxes are selected and one is unchecked, the top one would get unchecked too...

Comment: @santa are you saying that you took the jsfiddle code and added it to your code, and its not working? or there is something wrong with the jsfiddle example?

Comment: @santa I just updated the solution to check the all checkbox when the rest of the checkboxes are clicked.

Answer (score 1):

i think all you have to do is change your selector for your checkboxes. just get rid of the id selector. if you need to keep the id if you have other checkboxes on ur page then just put a div around your two tables.

so either change it to:

```
var $checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)").
```

and make no changes in ur html, or change it to

```
var $checkboxes = $("#tableContainer input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)").
```

and also change ur html to:

```
<div id="tableContainer">
<table id="myTbl1">
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="allCheckboxes"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="myTbl2">
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input name="" type="button" id="Btn">
</div>
```

Comment: I like the second solution, but it only addresses part of my previous code. For example, now when I check one of the checkboxes below it also selects the top one, which should only happen when ALL checkboxes in #myTbl2 are selected and if at least one is unchecked it should also uncheck the top one in myTbl1

Answer (score 1):

This probably performs the best over time:

```
$(function () {
  var $all = $("#allCheckboxes"),
      $others = $("input:checkbox").not($all);

    $all.bind("change", function () {
        $others.attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: I like how used $others.attr("checked", this.checked); instead of an if like I was doing! much cleaner. I updated my code with that. One thing to note, if using jquery 1.7+ use .on('click') rather than .bind()